# Multi touch rotation QT issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt, multi-touch

I'm currently trying the capture the orientation Azimuth (rotation of finger) of multi touch inputs in Windows when a user touches a specific dialog.
I'm using the QT C++ framework.
I'm testing everything with the surface laptop 3.
**The issue is that I'm always getting a value of 0 when I try using QT:**
According to QT documentation:

> qreal TouchPoint::rotation() const
>
> Returns the angular orientation of
> this touch point. The return value is in degrees, where zero (the
> default) indicates the finger or token is pointing upwards, a negative
> angle means it's rotated to the left, and a positive angle means it's
> rotated to the right. Most touchscreens do not detect rotation, so
> zero is the most common value.

```
//....
for (auto const& elem : touch.touchPoints()) {
        std::cout <<"Rotation:" <<elem.rotation();
        //.....
```

**Tried to check how can I capture this data natively directly (without the QT framework) and when I press the screen *I get values of 0 or 1*.**
Initially was expected to get more random values.
According to documentation:

> orientation
>
> Type: UINT32
>
> A pointer orientation, with a value between 0 and 359, where 0
> indicates a touch pointer aligned with the x-axis and pointing from
> left to right; increasing values indicate degrees of rotation in the
> clockwise direction.
>
> This field defaults to 0 if the device does not report orientation.

```
         #include <winuser.h>
          //......
         case PT_TOUCH:
              POINTER_TOUCH_INFO touchInfo;
              GetPointerTouchInfo(pointerId, &touchInfo);
              std::cout << "----------------------------------------" << std::endl; 
              std::cout << "Orientation" << touchInfo.orientation<<std::endl;
```

Above I presume the fact that orientation is typically exactly the same as orientation.

1. Any idea why I'm always getting 0 in QT? (is it a bug?)
2. Is my presumption correct? touchInfo.orientation is similar to rotation();

Comment: Why do you assume that there is any rotation/orientation information? Please explain how you're interacting with the touch input, and what you expect to get as orientation.

Comment: Please see GetPointerTouchInfo code. It prints out 0 and 1 BUT QT only prints 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is actually caused by 2 bugs in the current Windows Version.

1.Windows generates wrong vallues:

```
std::cout << "Orientation" << touchInfo.orientation<<std::endl; //is 0 or 1 because of Windows internal driver issues.
```

2.QT

```
for (auto const& elem : touch.touchPoints()) {
        std::cout <<"Rotation:" <<elem.rotation();
        //.....
```

QT uses internally the value provided by `touchInfo.orientation` above.
Because the issue is generated by Windows, in consequence QT also generates false values.

**I've already summited the BUG to Microsoft.
They've confirmed this is a bug.**
No solution but to just wait for Microsoft Windows team to solve this.